# How to navigate through XML response (SharePoint REST API)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, xml

I am using the SharePoint REST API to construct the endpoint URI as mentioned here

[Working with folders and files with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)

I have a Microsoft SharePoint location which has a folder and the folder contains multiple files. I used the following:

```
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/teams/Data/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/teams/Data/Shared Documents/TestFolder/2020-12-14')/files
```

The above returns the following XML response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="https://xyz.sharepoint.com/teams/Data/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
        <id>
            79b042e3-8a9a-4336-ac66-48a6d9e1202c
        </id>
        <title />
        <updated>
            2020-12-14T14:50:12Z
        </updated>
        <entry>
            <id>
                https://xyz.sharepoint.com/teams/Data/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/teams/Data/Shared Documents/TestFolder/2020-12-14/modified-bill-400394.xml')
            </id>
            <category term="SP.File" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <link rel="edit" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/teams/Data/Shared%20Documents/TestFolder/2020-12-14/modified-bill-400394.xml')" />
            <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Author" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Author" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/teams/Data/Shared%20Documents/TestFolder/2020-12-14/modified-bill-400394.xml')/Author" />
            <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CheckedOutByUser" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CheckedOutByUser" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/teams/Data/Shared%20Documents/TestFolder/2020-12-14/modified-bill-400394.xml')/CheckedOutByUser" />
            <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/EffectiveInformationRightsManagementSettings" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="EffectiveInformationRightsManagementSettings" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/teams/Data/Shared%20Documents/TestFolder/2020-12-14/modified-bill-400394.xml')/EffectiveInformationRightsManagementSettings" />
            <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/InformationRightsManagementSettings" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="InformationRightsManagementSettings" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/teams/Data/Shared%20Documents/TestFolder/2020-12-14/modified-bill-400394.xml')/InformationRightsManagementSettings" />
            <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ListItemAllFields" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ListItemAllFields" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/teams/Data/Shared%20Documents/TestFolder/2020-12-14/modified-bill-400394.xml')/ListItemAllFields" />
            <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/LockedByUser" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="LockedByUser" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/teams/Data/Shared%20Documents/TestFolder/2020-12-14/modified-bill-400394.xml')/LockedByUser" />
            <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ModifiedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ModifiedBy" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/teams/Data/Shared%20Documents/TestFolder/2020-12-14/modified-bill-400394.xml')/ModifiedBy" />
            <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Properties" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Properties" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/teams/Data/Shared%20Documents/TestFolder/2020-12-14/modified-bill-400394.xml')/Properties" />
            <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/VersionEvents" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="VersionEvents" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/teams/Data/Shared%20Documents/TestFolder/2020-12-14/modified-bill-400394.xml')/VersionEvents" />
            <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Versions" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Versions" href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/teams/Data/Shared%20Documents/TestFolder/2020-12-14/modified-bill-400394.xml')/Versions" />
            <title />
            <updated>
                2020-12-14T14:50:12Z
            </updated>
            <author>
                <name />
            </author>
            <content type="application/xml">
                <properties>
                    <CheckInComment>
                    </CheckInComment>
                    <CheckOutType m:type="Edm.Int32">
                        2
                    </CheckOutType>
                    <ContentTag>
                        {7CF22FF5-60B1-45C4-B843-00D6E1E66F8C},1,1
                    </ContentTag>
                    <CustomizedPageStatus m:type="Edm.Int32">
                        0
                    </CustomizedPageStatus>
                    <ETag>
                        "{7CF22FF5-60B1-45C4-B843-00D6E1E66F8C},1"
                    </ETag>
                    <Exists m:type="Edm.Boolean">
                        true
                    </Exists>
                    <IrmEnabled m:type="Edm.Boolean">
                        false
                    </IrmEnabled>
                    <Length m:type="Edm.Int64">
                        205
                    </Length>
                    <Level m:type="Edm.Byte">
                        1
                    </Level>
                    <LinkingUri m:null="true" />
                    <LinkingUrl>
                    </LinkingUrl>
                    <MajorVersion m:type="Edm.Int32">
                        1
                    </MajorVersion>
                    <MinorVersion m:type="Edm.Int32">
                        0
                    </MinorVersion>
                    <Name>
                        modified-bill-400394.xml
                    </Name>
                    <ServerRelativeUrl>
                        /teams/Data/Shared Documents/TestFolder/2020-12-14/modified-bill-400394.xml
                    </ServerRelativeUrl>
                    <TimeCreated m:type="Edm.DateTime">
                        2020-12-14T13:38:37Z
                    </TimeCreated>
                    <TimeLastModified m:type="Edm.DateTime">
                        2020-12-14T13:38:37Z
                    </TimeLastModified>
                    <Title>
                        modified-bill-400394.xml
                    </Title>
                    <UIVersion m:type="Edm.Int32">
                        512
                    </UIVersion>
                    <UIVersionLabel>
                        1.0
                    </UIVersionLabel>
                    <UniqueId m:type="Edm.Guid">
                        7cf22ff5-60b1-45c4-b843-00d6e1e66f8c
                    </UniqueId>
                </properties>
            </content>
        </entry>
       <entry>
          ----------
         ----------
      </entry>
      </feed>
```

There is a lot of unnecessary information here for my end goal. I only want the service call to return the information for `<ContentTag> </ContentTag>` for all `<entry> </entry>`.

How can I construct the URI to return the following desired output. Is there any way to use XQuery like path expression to get to what I want?

```
        <feed xml:base="https://xyz.sharepoint.com/teams/Data/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
                <id>
                    79b042e3-8a9a-4336-ac66-48a6d9e1202c
                </id>
                <title />
                <updated>
                    2020-12-14T14:50:12Z
                </updated>
                <entry>
                     <ContentTag>
                                {7CF22FF5-60B1-45C4-B843-00D6E1E66F8C},1,1
                            </ContentTag>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                     <ContentTag>
                                {A02D8998-A06C-4581-931D-00119FBD98AC},1,1
                            </ContentTag>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                     <ContentTag>
                                {56F12492-A080-4EC6-A229-0014FD75150A},1,1
                            </ContentTag>
                </entry>
            </feed>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below endpoint:

```
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/teams/Data/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/teams/Data/Shared Documents/TestFolder/2020-12-14')/files?$select=ContentTag
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. It worked. I initially thought that SQL like select statement only works on sharepoint lists. I am surprised to see that it works on XML structure as well.